# Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm having a little problem trying to do this:

Basically, I want to show another div if any error exists. This error comes from the payload to the next request.

But when I make the request for that (to have the error) and when I try to grab this error from the Redux state I'm having the problem that I put in the title 'Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement'

This is the function with problem:

Note: If the error doesn't not exist I can render very well the component.
Even when I have the error, if I reload the page the error "Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected." disappears and is showing me correctly the div that I want "You don't have the correct access".

```
const Users: FC = () => {
  const { error } = useSelector((state: State) => state.FleetUsers);

  return (
    <>
      <Layout title={t('Fleet_users.table.My_users')} />
      <LayoutFleet />
      {error ? (
        <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3 mt-3">
          <h2>You dont have the correct access</h2>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="table-container">
         <h2>You have the correct access</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Code behavior:

I'm using Redux state so basically if I have the "error" is in the memory and I grab it directly using `useSelector`.

```
  const { error } = useSelector((state: State) => state.FleetUsers);
```

This is the request :

```
export const fetchGroups = (
  token: string,
): ThunkAction<void, State, null, FluxStandardAction> => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(FetchAllGroupsRequest());
    try {
      const response = await axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `${API}/users/organization-user-group`,
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      });
      await response.data;
      dispatch(FetchAllGroupsSuccess(response.data));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      dispatch(FetchAllGroupsFailure(err));
    }
  };
};
```

This is the reducer:

```
   case FLEET_FETCH_ALL_GROUPS_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    case FLEET_FETCH_ALL_GROUPS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        groups: action.payload,
      };
    case FLEET_FETCH_ALL_GROUPS_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload.message,
      };
```

If someone knows how to fix this React problem I will appreciate it a lot.

Comment: I think the problem probably isn't in the code you posted - this often happens when a hook is called conditionally.  Is the Users component rendered conditionally?  If so, a workaround is to pass the errors value to the component as a prop, rather than use the selector in the conditionally rendered component.

Comment: @Abe is mostly right but the component can still use hooks even if the component is rendered conditionally.  So it's not this component that's the issue.  This error happens when you have a `return` statement before a hook or if you have a hook inside of an `if`.  Like `if (something) { return; } useSelector()` or `if (something) { useSelector() }`

Comment: Thank you @Linda Paiste, of course you are right, I didn't say that correclty

Comment: This error could happen if the component that renders User does something like: `const user = something?User():OtherComponent()`

Comment: @LindaPaiste what can be the correct solution then?